# Can JIRA JQL query how many times change to some status?

Tags: jira, jql

Here is the scenario, some JIRA ticket may be close and reopened several times.

New ---> In progress --> Done ---> ReOpened --> Done ---> ReOpened

Is there any way to query and count how many time's ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JQL don't have such kind of function - count()
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-65152